# e.target in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, events, attributes, target

When using flash, I was able to get to the focus of an event by accessing the event's "target" attribute.

so if I remember, it was something similar to.

```
button1.addEventListener(mouse_click, doSomething);

doSomething(e: Event){
    e.target.size = 50000;
}
```

And I'm looking for the equivalent in VB.

If you can give me it's common name across all languages, I'd be doubly grateful. I don't quite know what to search for aside from "event.target VB.net equivalent, and that's not returning anything.

Thanks in advance.

edit: for those new to flash. By focus, I mean the physical object that was clicked on. So the example given would be accessing the clicked button's size.

Comment: You are looking for hooking up an event handler in VB.NET - [Event Handler VB.NET](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=event+handler+vb.net&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: [Event Handling in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983610%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: These were both really helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick.aspx#Y0

```
    Sub GreetingBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'When the button is clicked,
        'change the button text, and disable it.

        Dim clickedButton As Button = sender
        clickedButton.Text = "...button clicked..."
        clickedButton.Enabled = False
    End Sub
```

The first parameter (sender by default) references the focused object. You can access it as you would any other normal variable, but it's information won't appear in the auto complete list unless you set it "As" that specific data type.

So I ended up with this

```
    Private Sub nw_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Windows.Forms.Button, ByVal e AsSystem.EventArgs) Handles nw_btn.Click
        sender.Hide()
    End Sub
```

Comment: While you're starting with VB, make sure to turn Option Strict On to catch type coersions (like `Dim clickedButton As Button = sender`). Also, make sure to mark your accepted response as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In VB you can wire up event handlers declaratively using the WithEvents keyword or imperatively using AddHandler.

```
Private WithEvents myButton

' OR

Public Sub New
  Dim newButton = New Button()
  AddHandler newButton.Click, AddressOf MyClickHandler
End New

'To consume it you declare a method as follows:
' The Handles clause is used when declaring WithEvents
Private Sub MyClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myButton.Click
  ' The sender has a handle on the object that raised the event (aka the button)
  Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
  btn.Size = New Size(500, 500)

End Sub
```

Comment: Although it's beyond the scope of what I needed at the time, It's an interesting bit of knowledge none the less.

It's my first time looking at declarative programming, so thank you.